# django is_valid() throws database error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

My is_valid() function throws a database error. Am making use of a an alias database(not the default one) and hence am not able to validate my form. My Application table is in database2.
 Code:

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
      default:{
                 database1
       }
      'database2':{
                  database2
       }
}
```

models.py

```
class Application(models.Model)
            application_name = models.CharField(max_length=48,primary_key=True )
            application_version = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3,decimal_places=0,blank=False,null=False)
```

forms.py

```
class Application_form(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

        super(Application_form,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Application
```

views.py

```
Application_Form=Application_form(request.POST)    
       if Application_Form.is_valid():
           print "true"
       else:
           print "false"
```

Comment: It is looking into the default database while validating uniqueness, so it does not find the application table.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Application_form(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

        super(Application_form,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Application.objects.using('database2')

    class Meta:
        model = Application
```

[Link to documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset)

Comment: Thnx Samuele Mattiuzzo. I tried the code sent by you. Its throwing this error 'Application_form' object has no attribute 'using'

Comment: `using` is for queryset not form.

Comment: Sorry, my mind was slower than my fingers. Fixed answer with tested production code I'm using, too. Sorry again!

Comment: init3, Sorry it still dosen't work. It still throws the same error

Comment: that's strange - because I'm really using this on production. Could you please update your question with the stacktrace of the error?